# Improve performance in CKEditor integration with google web fonts

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

[How can I add(programatically) google fonts to ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986548/how-can-i-addprogramatically-google-fonts-to-ckeditor)

Can we improve the performance here. I have around 400 web fonts `e.g. Google Fonts` and concat all the css into contents.css take a bit long. How i can improve it?

Can I add based on what font user select and dynamically I will add the css into the head?

Comment: 400!? I think that you should reduce this number.

Comment: even if i did. is there any way to improve the performance and don't load all the webfonts css into contents.css.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this Apurv.  I too would like the ability to use google fonts in CKeditor 4.

Comment: What i am doing is :- I am dynamically adding the css file when the user select any webfont and apply in the head of the html. that will be fast.

Comment: Apurv, how did you do this?

Comment: @OskarRough First of all you need to add all the fonts in the font-dropdown of Ckeditor, by adding in config.font_names ="//Your font list", When you some one select the font from the dropdown trigger the callback with the font_name to your function , which will add the css into the head of the html page.